# Dispatching action from custom command or plugin using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am using cypress for E2E testing of my angular web application.

I can able to dispatch the action from the test file as below,

```
 describe('Views', () => {
    it('Will update the token', () => {
      cy.window().its('store').invoke('dispatch', { payload: 'abcdefgh', type: 'UPDATE_TOKEN' });
    });
  });
```

**Issue is**

but I couldn't use the same from the custom command or Plugin

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  
        cy.request({
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${apiUrl}/v1/verify_otp`,
          body: {
            user: {
              email: Cypress.env('userName'),
              otp: '1234'// As of dev, any OTP will work here
            },
          },
        }).then((res) => {

          cy.window().its('store').invoke('dispatch', { payload: 'abcd', type: 'UPDATE_TOKEN' });
         
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to visit a route in the app first for the store to be available, and then use `then`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${apiUrl}/v1/verify_otp`,
    body: {
      user: {
        email: Cypress.env('userName'),
        otp: '1234'
      },
    }
  }).then(() => {
    cy.visit('/');
    cy.window()
      .its('store')
      .then(store => {
        store.dispatch({payload: 'abcd', type: 'UPDATE_TOKEN'});
      });
  });
});
```